# Getting exact pixel from texture

Tags: opengl, matrix, fragment-shader

I have a question about textures in OpenGL. I am trying to use them for GPGPU operations but I am stuck at beggining. I have created a texture like this (4x4 int matrix).

```
OGLTexImageFloat dataTexImage = new OGLTexImageFloat(4, 4, 4);
dataTexImage.setPixel(0, 0, 0, 0);
dataTexImage.setPixel(0, 1, 0, 10);
dataTexImage.setPixel(0, 2, 0, 5);
dataTexImage.setPixel(0, 3, 0, 15);
dataTexImage.setPixel(1, 0, 0, 10);
dataTexImage.setPixel(1, 1, 0, 0);
dataTexImage.setPixel(1, 2, 0, 2);
dataTexImage.setPixel(1, 3, 0, 1000);
dataTexImage.setPixel(2, 0, 0, 5);
dataTexImage.setPixel(2, 1, 0, 2);
dataTexImage.setPixel(2, 2, 0, 0);
dataTexImage.setPixel(2, 3, 0, 2);
dataTexImage.setPixel(3, 0, 0, 15);
dataTexImage.setPixel(3, 1, 0, 1000);
dataTexImage.setPixel(3, 2, 0, 2);
dataTexImage.setPixel(3, 3, 0, 0);
texture = new OGLTexture2D(gl, dataTexImage);
```

Now I would like to add value from [1,1] matrix position to value of each pixel (matrix entry). As I am speaking about every picture I should probably do it in fragment shader. But i dont know how can i get exact pixel form texture ([1,1] entry from matrix). Can someone explain me, how to do this?

Comment: "*As I am speaking about every picture I should probably do it in fragment shader.*" You're adding ***16*** values. The time spent uploading and downloading the data to the GPU will take up longer than the actual addition. Just use the CPU.

Comment: I wanna use it for much bigger datasets, but from beginning I have a small matrix so it is easier for me to imagine the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a single constant value (i.e. a value from [1,1]) to the entire image (every pixel of the rendered image), then you should pass that constant value as a separate `uniform` value into your shader program.

Then in the fragment shader, add this constant value to the current pixel color. The current pixel color comes as an input `vec4` from your vertex shader.